# break Grand Central Dispatch run

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

i use

```
 dispatch_async(getDataQueue,^{
    //do many work task A
    dispatch_aysnc (mainQueue, ^{
    //do
};
}
)
```

if i press back key,and the gcd not finished its task A,i want to break the dispatch_async.how to do

Comment: What do you mean "break" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *flag* to continue working all the time it's false:

```
// Somewhere accessible from the task's block and from the view controller
__block BOOL quit = NO;

dispatch_async(getDataQueue,^{
    dispatch_aysnc (mainQueue, ^{

        if (!quit)
        {
            // do first thing
        }

        if (!quit)
        {
             // do second thing
        }

        while (!quit)
        {
            // do lots of things
        }

    });
});
```

And then you can stop the background task simply doing:

```
quit = YES;
```

This is the preferred method of stopping any background task anyway as it allows the task to perform clean-up without before forced to terminate.

Comment: shouldn't 'BOOL quit' be the type __block or sysnthesize BOOL quit? Is it work with type static BOOL also?

Comment: use bool quit only cancel mainQueue,if i want to cancel chiledQueue,for example not download

Comment: @pengwang Just add checking of the `quit` flag whereever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.  One of the fundamental truths about GCD is that once you dispatch a block, it will run **no matter what** as long as the queue is not suspended.  If you need cancelable async operations, you will need to use `NSOperation`

Comment: @trojanfoe You got me there, but that is a special case ^^;

Comment: Dispatching a block only means queueing it for execution. If you call `dispatch_suspend` before the given block gets executed, then the block will not be executed. So, strictly speaking, what you wrote is not true.

Comment: @lawicko While technically true, it is not practical.  I edited my answer to reflect this information though.

Comment: And one of the fundamental truths of pretty much *any* operation queue solution (that interoperates with standard system libraries) is that once a unit of work is in flight, you can't meaningfully cancel it unless it cooperatively checks for some condition and returns early. (Yes, you can kill a thread, but then you've leaked any memory allocated but not yet freed on that thread.) This is true of NSOperationQueues too, although those do have support for canceling not-yet-started work units as the original answer indicates.